# find optimal parameters for SVM from tune() in R?

Tags: r, svm

I am optimizing the gamma and cost variable using the tune function

```
obj<-best.tune(svm,V28 ~ .,data=data,gamma=exp(seq(from=log(1/nrow(data)), to=2,len=10)),cost=5^(-5:5))
> summary(obj)
```

I get the following:

best.tune(svm, V28 ~ ., data = data, gamma = exp(seq(from = log(1/nrow(data)), to = 2, len = 10)), 
    cost = 5^(-5:5))

```
Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  0.00032 0.0016 0.008 0.04 0.2 1 5 25 125 625 3125 
      gamma:  0.000691085 0.001937334 0.005430972 0.01522477 0.04267993 0.1196456 0.3354052 0.9402489 2.635821 7.389056 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  1442
```

How do I find the optimal gamma and cost function from the object function?
I am not to figure this out.

this is the training data used(part of it)

```
-1.00E+00   5.81E-02    2.77E-04    -1.00E+00   5.25E-02    5.18E-04    -1.00E+00   4.83E-02    6.23E-04    -1.00E+00   4.45E-02    8.04E-04    -9.76E-01   4.62E-02    8.49E-04    -9.56E-01   4.78E-02    9.06E-04    -9.24E-01   4.88E-02    8.53E-04    -9.00E-01   4.99E-02    9.59E-04    -8.68E-01   5.22E-02    1.13E-03    -1.00E+00
-4.00E-02   4.85E-02    9.65E-04    1.84E-01    5.30E-02    1.48E-03    3.58E-01    4.95E-02    1.26E-03    4.55E-01    4.22E-02    1.10E-03    5.27E-01    3.95E-02    9.67E-04    5.73E-01    3.56E-02    9.33E-04    6.12E-01    3.32E-02    8.54E-04    6.40E-01    3.10E-02    7.69E-04    6.42E-01    2.92E-02    6.90E-04    1.00E+00
-7.60E-01   9.54E-02    3.88E-03    -6.33E-01   9.13E-02    2.68E-03    -6.67E-01   8.81E-02    3.09E-03    -7.19E-01   1.06E-01    3.35E-03    -6.80E-01   1.13E-01    3.88E-03    -5.78E-01   1.04E-01    3.39E-03    -5.50E-01   9.33E-02    3.32E-03    -5.29E-01   8.79E-02    3.40E-03    -5.33E-01   8.40E-02    3.33E-03    -1.00E+00
-8.40E-01   5.67E-02    4.26E-04    -8.78E-01   4.79E-02    5.36E-04    -9.01E-01   5.18E-02    5.98E-04    -9.17E-01   6.44E-02    9.49E-04    -9.29E-01   7.40E-02    1.56E-03    -8.71E-01   7.50E-02    1.58E-03    -7.85E-01   7.28E-02    1.43E-03    -7.23E-01   7.11E-02    1.55E-03    -6.49E-01   7.11E-02    1.58E-03    -1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   3.89E-02    1.58E-04    -1.00E+00   3.63E-02    3.12E-04    -1.00E+00   4.04E-02    4.10E-04    -1.00E+00   4.33E-02    4.68E-04    -1.00E+00   4.34E-02    5.52E-04    -9.69E-01   4.50E-02    8.68E-04    -9.34E-01   4.67E-02    1.05E-03    -9.09E-01   4.97E-02    1.32E-03    -8.98E-01   5.26E-02    1.57E-03    -1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   8.28E-02    2.45E-03    -1.00E+00   7.63E-02    1.87E-03    -1.00E+00   8.04E-02    2.72E-03    -9.01E-01   1.04E-01    5.26E-03    -7.40E-01   1.05E-01    4.45E-03    -5.78E-01   9.56E-02    3.78E-03    -4.84E-01   9.06E-02    4.04E-03    -4.24E-01   8.84E-02    4.21E-03    -3.67E-01   8.68E-02    4.41E-03    -1.00E+00
-7.60E-01   1.16E-01    2.57E-03    -6.73E-01   1.12E-01    3.19E-03    -6.30E-01   1.13E-01    3.46E-03    -5.04E-01   9.78E-02    3.05E-03    -4.08E-01   8.43E-02    3.18E-03    -3.11E-01   7.95E-02    3.36E-03    -2.15E-01   7.34E-02    3.22E-03    -1.27E-01   6.77E-02    3.21E-03    -4.54E-02   6.57E-02    3.31E-03    1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   6.36E-02    3.38E-04    -1.00E+00   7.45E-02    1.31E-03    -9.51E-01   8.07E-02    1.83E-03    -8.35E-01   7.54E-02    1.58E-03    -7.93E-01   7.10E-02    1.63E-03    -7.33E-01   7.54E-02    1.98E-03    -6.92E-01   7.44E-02    1.92E-03    -6.93E-01   7.18E-02    1.82E-03    -7.05E-01   6.99E-02    1.77E-03    -1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   6.48E-02    1.29E-03    -1.00E+00   6.28E-02    1.37E-03    -1.00E+00   6.58E-02    1.77E-03    -9.17E-01   7.22E-02    2.39E-03    -8.22E-01   6.76E-02    1.92E-03    -7.42E-01   6.95E-02    1.78E-03    -6.82E-01   7.21E-02    1.67E-03    -6.12E-01   7.07E-02    1.65E-03    -5.51E-01   6.85E-02    1.63E-03    1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   6.04E-02    5.99E-04    -1.00E+00   6.60E-02    1.35E-03    -9.26E-01   7.56E-02    1.90E-03    -8.26E-01   8.07E-02    1.75E-03    -7.16E-01   8.40E-02    2.14E-03    -6.49E-01   8.49E-02    2.34E-03    -5.64E-01   8.54E-02    2.27E-03    -5.10E-01   8.51E-02    2.47E-03    -4.83E-01   8.58E-02    2.77E-03    1.00E+00
-8.80E-01   6.93E-02    7.20E-04    -9.39E-01   7.65E-02    2.44E-03    -8.52E-01   7.72E-02    2.27E-03    -6.94E-01   7.20E-02    1.89E-03    -5.86E-01   7.22E-02    2.40E-03    -4.93E-01   7.59E-02    3.32E-03    -4.39E-01   7.94E-02    4.24E-03    -4.04E-01   8.19E-02    4.85E-03    -4.06E-01   7.88E-02    4.06E-03    -1.00E+00
-9.20E-01   9.62E-02    2.56E-03    -7.55E-01   8.88E-02    3.28E-03    -6.67E-01   8.27E-02    3.85E-03    -5.87E-01   7.92E-02    4.41E-03    -5.27E-01   7.72E-02    4.43E-03    -4.84E-01   7.54E-02    4.21E-03    -4.50E-01   7.15E-02    3.87E-03    -4.29E-01   6.77E-02    3.56E-03    -4.01E-01   6.57E-02    3.28E-03    1.00E+00
-1.00E+00   1.08E-01    2.91E-03    -1.00E+00   9.85E-02    2.90E-03    -9.01E-01   9.40E-02    3.23E-03    -8.02E-01   9.90E-02    3.61E-03    -7.16E-01   9.52E-02    3.61E-03    -7.11E-01   9.18E-02    3.69E-03    -7.13E-01   8.81E-02    3.29E-03    -7.04E-01   9.10E-02    3.28E-03    -6.62E-01   9.26E-02    3.44E-03    -1.00E+00
2.00E-01    1.03E-01    4.47E-03    2.04E-02    9.48E-02    4.01E-03    1.23E-02    8.83E-02    3.87E-03    8.26E-03    8.51E-02    3.58E-03    5.92E-03    7.95E-02    3.31E-03    4.00E-02    7.19E-02    3.08E-03    6.57E-02    6.74E-02    2.86E-03    8.59E-02    6.40E-02    2.74E-03    8.62E-02    6.05E-02    2.61E-03    1.00E+00
2.00E-01    1.09E-01    2.97E-03    -1.02E-01   9.72E-02    2.85E-03    -2.35E-01   9.66E-02    2.59E-03    -2.56E-01   9.56E-02    2.79E-03    -2.90E-01   9.34E-02    2.87E-03    -2.44E-01   9.90E-02    3.33E-03    -1.70E-01   1.00E-01    3.92E-03    -6.93E-02   9.75E-02    3.94E-03    2.27E-03    9.33E-02    3.74E-03    1.00E+00
```

and the validation data:

```
-7.60E-01   1.28E-01    5.63E-03    -6.73E-01   1.02E-01    3.53E-03    -6.79E-01   8.37E-02    3.18E-03    -6.78E-01   7.88E-02    2.81E-03    -6.45E-01   7.51E-02    2.66E-03    -6.31E-01   7.76E-02    2.51E-03    -6.51E-01   8.10E-02    2.84E-03    -6.57E-01   8.02E-02    2.64E-03    -6.64E-01   7.99E-02    2.64E-03
-2.00E-01   5.27E-02    1.09E-03    -2.86E-01   7.98E-02    2.51E-03    -3.46E-01   8.32E-02    2.72E-03    -3.64E-01   7.52E-02    1.96E-03    -3.85E-01   7.11E-02    1.73E-03    -4.31E-01   7.25E-02    1.72E-03    -4.81E-01   7.29E-02    2.15E-03    -5.29E-01   7.41E-02    2.16E-03    -5.71E-01   7.47E-02    2.06E-03
-9.20E-01   1.09E-01    1.98E-03    -7.55E-01   1.01E-01    1.96E-03    -5.06E-01   8.44E-02    1.99E-03    -3.88E-01   7.64E-02    1.69E-03    -3.37E-01   7.53E-02    1.84E-03    -3.16E-01   7.45E-02    1.74E-03    -3.08E-01   7.47E-02    1.84E-03    -3.13E-01   7.25E-02    1.84E-03    -3.31E-01   7.32E-02    2.06E-03
-4.00E-01   1.40E-01    1.03E-02    -1.84E-01   1.46E-01    8.11E-03    -8.64E-02   1.25E-01    6.35E-03    -4.13E-02   1.12E-01    6.78E-03    0.00E+00    1.06E-01    6.68E-03    5.78E-02    9.79E-02    6.75E-03    9.69E-02    9.16E-02    6.58E-03    1.19E-01    8.64E-02    6.25E-03    1.32E-01    8.40E-02    5.92E-03
-1.00E+00   1.30E-01    2.73E-03    -7.96E-01   1.22E-01    3.67E-03    -6.79E-01   1.10E-01    4.17E-03    -6.20E-01   9.91E-02    4.31E-03    -5.92E-01   8.88E-02    4.39E-03    -5.87E-01   8.22E-02    4.12E-03    -6.02E-01   7.98E-02    3.89E-03    -6.23E-01   7.58E-02    3.71E-03    -6.35E-01   6.99E-02    3.45E-03
-8.80E-01   1.23E-01    3.81E-03    -9.39E-01   1.04E-01    3.86E-03    -7.28E-01   8.91E-02    3.14E-03    -6.20E-01   8.70E-02    2.60E-03    -5.86E-01   8.95E-02    3.24E-03    -5.82E-01   9.51E-02    3.45E-03    -5.71E-01   9.52E-02    3.51E-03    -5.43E-01   9.03E-02    3.15E-03    -5.28E-01   8.43E-02    3.10E-03
-6.80E-01   1.04E-01    1.45E-03    -4.29E-01   9.48E-02    1.64E-03    -3.09E-01   8.33E-02    1.48E-03    -2.89E-01   7.25E-02    1.60E-03    -2.78E-01   7.03E-02    1.80E-03    -3.24E-01   6.88E-02    1.86E-03    -3.63E-01   6.40E-02    1.79E-03    -3.68E-01   6.25E-02    1.77E-03    -3.65E-01   6.19E-02    1.83E-03
0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    0.00E+00    1.24E-03    2.11E-05    0.00E+00    9.76E-03    4.52E-04    -1.78E-02   2.57E-02    2.14E-03    -8.00E-02   4.10E-02    4.90E-03    -1.28E-01   4.69E-02    5.35E-03    -1.61E-01   4.52E-02    4.46E-03    -2.00E-01   4.35E-02    4.10E-03
-7.20E-01   7.71E-02    8.23E-04    -7.96E-01   8.23E-02    1.40E-03    -8.15E-01   8.13E-02    1.38E-03    -8.76E-01   8.26E-02    1.85E-03    -8.82E-01   8.35E-02    2.01E-03    -8.71E-01   8.26E-02    2.91E-03    -8.37E-01   8.63E-02    3.54E-03    -7.62E-01   8.95E-02    4.07E-03    -6.83E-01   8.88E-02    4.16E-03
0.00E+00    5.08E-03    8.65E-05    0.00E+00    1.73E-02    7.91E-04    -2.47E-02   4.49E-02    3.58E-03    -7.44E-02   6.39E-02    5.84E-03    -7.69E-02   7.28E-02    5.89E-03    -8.44E-02   7.83E-02    6.80E-03    -9.00E-02   8.37E-02    7.45E-03    -8.59E-02   8.14E-02    7.49E-03    -8.62E-02   8.15E-02    7.48E-03
-1.00E+00   4.90E-02    1.57E-04    -1.00E+00   4.13E-02    4.12E-04    -9.63E-01   4.00E-02    7.30E-04    -9.34E-01   3.82E-02    7.09E-04    -8.76E-01   4.21E-02    1.30E-03    -8.09E-01   4.41E-02    1.65E-03    -7.75E-01   4.84E-02    2.06E-03    -7.56E-01   5.35E-02    2.51E-03    -7.48E-01   5.98E-02    2.62E-03
-3.60E-01   9.67E-02    1.37E-03    -4.29E-01   8.30E-02    2.07E-03    -5.06E-01   9.44E-02    2.51E-03    -5.37E-01   8.66E-02    2.23E-03    -5.38E-01   8.05E-02    2.21E-03    -5.64E-01   7.74E-02    2.23E-03    -5.85E-01   7.52E-02    2.31E-03    -5.62E-01   7.36E-02    2.27E-03    -5.37E-01   7.25E-02    2.18E-03
-1.00E+00   8.18E-02    1.47E-03    -1.00E+00   8.63E-02    1.29E-03    -1.00E+00   7.40E-02    1.44E-03    -9.67E-01   6.56E-02    1.67E-03    -9.41E-01   6.21E-02    1.81E-03    -9.20E-01   6.17E-02    1.83E-03    -8.30E-01   6.18E-02    1.81E-03    -7.26E-01   6.07E-02    1.77E-03    -6.35E-01   5.95E-02    1.76E-03
-1.00E+00   8.54E-02    2.09E-03    -1.00E+00   9.88E-02    2.38E-03    -9.01E-01   9.11E-02    1.80E-03    -8.68E-01   8.31E-02    1.97E-03    -9.05E-01   7.70E-02    1.84E-03    -9.11E-01   7.07E-02    1.89E-03    -9.13E-01   6.75E-02    1.84E-03    -9.20E-01   6.52E-02    1.91E-03    -9.32E-01   6.31E-02    1.89E-03
-6.00E-01   1.37E-01    1.95E-03    -5.10E-01   1.07E-01    3.15E-03    -4.69E-01   9.38E-02    3.17E-03    -4.46E-01   8.57E-02    2.87E-03    -4.32E-01   7.86E-02    2.64E-03    -4.44E-01   7.63E-02    2.56E-03    -4.64E-01   7.68E-02    2.62E-03    -4.68E-01   7.62E-02    2.66E-03    -4.65E-01   7.45E-02    2.74E-03
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a minimal, sufficient [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can run the code and inspect the objects involved. Also, be sure to include all necessary library calls in the code so we know where your functions are coming form.

Comment: I added the data(this is just a sample,the data is huge),I am not using any use made functions.

Comment: What package does the `best.tune` function come from? It is not a base function.

Answer (score 1):

This shows the internal structure of the object

```
str(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,hope it helps someone else. The way you obtain the gamma,cost or any parameter in a model is the following:

```
model_obj$gamma

model_obj$cost
```

just use the model where you store your classifier $ parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to testing cost and gamma for range between 2^-5 ~ 2^5. And generate confusion matrix for each value combination and select the cost and gamma value for the highest accuracy.